# How do i pass STL set as function parameters

Tags: c++, function, debugging, stl, set

This is a dumbed down version of my code , bascially i am trying to pass STL SET as a function parameter but i am unable to do so . I get the following errors

> error : cannot convert
>   'std::set,std::allocator to 'int' for
>   arguement '1' to void foo(int)
>
> error: template arguement 1 is invalid
>
> error: template arguement 2 is invalid
>
> error: template arguement 3 is invalid

This is the code sample which the errors were derived from

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

void foo(set<foobar>);

class foobar
{
   public:

   int x;

};

int main()
{

  set<foobar> foobar_set;

  foo(foobar_set);


}

void foo(set<foobar> foobar_set)
{

}
```

Question : How do i pass STL Sets as function parameters ??

How long do STL Set exist for , Local scope or Global scope??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's consider things in order, the way the compiler (mostly) does. When we've looked at this much code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

void foo(set<foobar>);
```

...what type is `foobar`? Short answer: based on what we've seen so far, we have no clue -- and neither does the compiler. Move the declaration for `foo` to *after* the definition of `foobar` (on which it depends).

```
class foobar
{
    // ...
};

void foo(set<foobar>); // now the compiler knows what `foobar` means

int main()
{
  set<foobar> foobar_set;

  foo(foobar_set);   // so now this can work
}
```

Now a little addition: chances are pretty good that you don't really want to pass a `set<whatever>` by value -- that'll result in copying the whole set. You probably want to pass it by const reference:

```
void foo(set<foobar> const &);
```

...and make sure that your definition of `foo` matches:

```
void foo(set<foobar> const &) {}
```

For "small" types (e.g., `char`, `short`, `int`) you generally want to pass by value. For something that's (potentially) as large as a `set<whatever>` passing by (`const`) reference is generally preferred. It's not *always* better, but it's generally at least acceptable. Passing by value can be faster under the right circumstances, but it can also be slower--sometimes a *lot* slower, so unless you're sure you know what you're doing, passing by `const` reference is generally the safe choice.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is here:

```
void foo(set<foobar>);

class foobar
{
   public:

   int x;

};
```

When you're prototyping `foo`, the type `foobar` hasn't yet been declared and the compiler doesn't know what to make of it. When I tried compiling this [at ideone](http://ideone.com/mgpw8U), the first error message I got was

```
prog.cpp:5:14: error: ‘foobar’ was not declared in this scope
               void foo(set<foobar>);
```

You can fix this by reordering the definition of `foobar` and the prototype or by forward-declaring `foobar`. Once you've done that, the errors should clear up. There's nothing special about passing `set`s as parameters.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

When declaring foo(), class foobar has not been declared. Simply moving the definition of foobar before foo() can solve your problem.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try forward declaration for the foobar class before declaring the function.
This is also recommended way if you dont want to move you complete class above the foo function.

```
class foobar;
void foo(set<foobar>); // now the compiler knows what `foobar` means
```

I am sure this should solve your problem or at least gives you new errors ;)